# Method App\Http\Controllers\UserController::create does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having the issue when loading the /usarios/create (/user/create) and being return an error of:

> **BadMethodCallException**
>
> Method App\Http\Controllers\UserController::create does not exist.

**Route web file:**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('usuarios', 'UserController@index');
```

**UserController:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
    $users = User::all( );
    return view( 'usuarios.index', ['users' => $users]);
}
}

function create()
{
    return view ('usuarios.create');
}

function store(Request $request)
{        
}

function show($id)
{        
}

function edit($id)
{    
}

function update(Request $request, $id)
{        
}

function destroy($id)
{        
}
```

**My version Laravel is 6.0**

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Remove `@index` from your resource route. Resource routes only need the controller name.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove @index. Even so it continues with the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra "}" on your controller, right below index method.

And you'll need to close the class, adding a } after destroy method.

Answer (score 2):

In `Route::resource()` has 7 methods bind.

If you want to use `Route::resource()` then you should pass two params, base path and Controller class. [see](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

SO you should pass like this.

```
Route::resource('usuarios', 'UserController');
```

Notice that:

`Route::resource('usuarios', 'UserController');` second parameter is a controller class name.

where you are using `Route::resource('usuarios', 'UserController@index');` is not a class, passing index method exits in UserController class.